# In Python, what is a good way of avoiding many "nested" objects within objects

Tags: python, oop

I need to make a series of objects that each take an object as an attribute. This makes accessing attributes deep within the structure a bit ugly.

Example:

```
class ClassOne: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.object_two = ClassTwo()

class ClassTwo: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.object_three = ClassThree()

class ClassThree: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.object_four = ClassFour()

class ClassFour: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_value = 5

object_one = ClassOne()
print(object_one.object_two.object_three.object_four.some_value)

# Output: 5
```

Are there any good methods are there for dealing with this problem or avoiding it all together?

Comment: I think that mainly comes down to program design and using design patterns appropriately. If you are new to programming (or not), searching for 'design patterns' and how they are used could help.

Comment: Also note, **every class has other objects in it**. This is normal. `5` is an object

Comment: "This makes accessing attributes deep within the structure a bit ugly." So, this is code smell. As stated previously, this generally means you have to rethink the design. But without something more concrete, it is hard to say what you should do here

Comment: The only real advice we can offer is to rethink your assumption that you need a series of nested objects at all.

Comment: @AlecPetersen I took your advice to look into common design patterns and it seems the "Composite" structural pattern fits well. I am quite new to OOP so this will come in very handy, thank you.